# Locking file after Opening it in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to open an **MS Word document** in web browser control and after opening that file, I want to lock that file that no body can open or use that file until I close my program. Is it possible? Please help...
Thanks!

Comment: Why does it matter if other people can open the file if it's being displayed in a browser? It's not like they can save their changes back to the server. If your intent is to allow editing of documents, you might be better served going with an existing solution like SharePoint.

Comment: 'FileStream' is one solution but with 'FileStream' the original formatting of the file is lost. I want to open the original file.

Answer (score 0):

There's no explicit way to lock a file without using native  Windows/NTFS APIs.

Easy solution it to [open a write stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openwrite.aspx) and not close it until you want to release it.

I'm not sure how 'elegant' it is though. This will prevent others from opening the file, including our application, if you forget to close the stream.

Hope this helps.